# Unable to get Python function for calculating number of iterations to work correctly

Tags: python, function, loops, conditional-statements

I've recently started learning Python. I was doing some exercises on the Control Structures section of the course and everything was going fine until I got stumped on the last problem. I've been looking at it for three days now, and I'm pretty sure that the solution is quite obvious. Here is a description in the exercise:

> Start with any number. If the number is divisible by 3, divide it by
>   3. Otherwise, add 2 to the number. Eventually, no matter what number you begin with, this series will run into 1.  For example, imagine we
>   started with the number 5: 5 is not divisible by 3, so 5 + 2 = 7 7 is
>   not divisible by 3, so 7 + 2 = 9 9 is divisible by 3, so 9 / 3 = 3 3
>   is divisible by 3, so 3 / 3 = 1
>
> Start with 5, this sequence converges on 1 in 4 iterations: 5 -> 7, 7
>   -> 9, 9 -> 3, 3 -> 1.
>
> Write a function called joyner. joyner should have one parameter, an
>   integer. It should return the number of iterations required to reach 1
>   for the first time.

I ran the function I wrote on a page that tests my function with different integers. Every time it gave me an error (saying how many iterations were expected and how many my program calculated) I managed to fix the program for that integer, but the following integer tested would give me an error again. The code is below is the final re-write before I decided to come here to ask for help.

```
def joyner(num):
    count = 0
    while num % 3 != 0:
        # print("num not divisible by 3")
        num = num + 2
        # print("added 2")
        count += 1
        # print(count)
        if num % 3 == 0:
            # print("num is divisible by 3")
            num /= 3
            # print("divided by 3")
            count += 1
            # print(count)


    while num % 3 == 0:
        # print("num is divisible by 3")
        num /= 3
        # print("divided by 3")
        count += 1
        # print(count)

    return count
```

Here are the results:

> We found the following problems with your submission:
>
> We tested your code with num = 15. We expected joyner to return the
>   int 5. However, it returned the int 1.
>
> We tested your code with num = 29. We expected joyner to return the
>   int 10. However, it returned the int 3.
>
> We tested your code with num = 65. We expected joyner to return the
>   int 8. However, it returned the int 3.
>
> We tested your code with num = 12. We expected joyner to return the
>   int 3. However, it returned the int 1.
>
> We tested your code with num = 32. We expected joyner to return the
>   int 6. However, it returned the int 4.
>
> Note that these errors may have prevented us from checking your
>   submission in other ways, so fixing these problems may cause other
>   problems to show up next time. Keep trying! This is what debugging is
>   all about.
>
> ---
>
> The following things were correct about your submission:
>
> We expected to find a function named joyner in your code, and we did.
>
> We tested your code with num = 5. We expected joyner to return the int
>   4, and it did.
>
> We tested your code with num = 27. We expected joyner to return the
>   int 3, and it did.
>
> We tested your code with num = 16. We expected joyner to return the
>   int 3, and it did.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with your code is that it assumes that when a number is no longer divisible by 3 that it reached 1, that is regarding your second loop, for example 15 is divisible by 3, it becomes 5, which is not divisible but also not 1.

Overall think about it this way, a number may be either divisible or not at once, so it should happen in one loop, and you should stop when you reach 1.

Answer (score 0):

The premise of your task is not correct:

> Start with any number. If the number is divisible by 3, divide it by 3. Otherwise, add 2 to the number. Eventually, no matter what number you begin with, this series will run into 1.

```
number = 4

4 + 2 = 6        # 4 is not divisible by 3, add 2
6 / 3 = 2        # 6 is     divisible by 3 -> 2
2 + 2 = 4        # 2 is not divisible by 3, add 2
4 + 2 = 6        # 4 is not divisible by 3, add 2  --> cycle - no solution.
```

If there is a solution, this finds it:

```
def joyner(num): 
    count = 0
    seen = set()
    while num != 1:
        if num in seen: 
            return None
        else:
            seen.add(num)
        if num % 3 == 0:
            num = num // 3
        else:
            num += 2
        count += 1

    return count
```

Test it:

```
i = 0    
for k,c in d.items():
    if c is None:
        continue
    print(k,":",c, end="     ")
    i += 1
    if i % 6 == 0:
        print()
        i = 0
```

Output of solutions from 1 to 99:

```
 1 : 0       3 : 1      5 : 4      7 : 3     9 : 2      11 : 7     
13 : 6      15 : 5     17 : 6     19 : 5     21 : 4     23 : 5     
25 : 4      27 : 3     29 : 10    31 : 9     33 : 8     35 : 9     
37 : 8      39 : 7     41 : 8     43 : 7     45 : 6     47 : 9     
49 : 8      51 : 7     53 : 8     55 : 7     57 : 6     59 : 7     
61 : 6      63 : 5     65 : 8     67 : 7     69 : 6     71 : 7     
73 : 6      75 : 5     77 : 6     79 : 5     81 : 4     83 : 13     
85 : 12     87 : 11    89 : 12    91 : 11    93 : 10    95 : 11     
97 : 10     99 : 9
```

Not viable:

```
[ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 
 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 
 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98]
```

Your algo only works for *odd* numbers.

> We tested your code with num = 12. We expected joyner to return the int 3. However, it returned the int 1.

does not work *at all*

Comment: Now that you mention it, I edited the description because it didn't seem to make sense. Perhaps I was wrong to do so.
>Start with any number. If the number is divisible by 3, divide it by 3. >Otherwise, add 2 to the number. Eventually, no matter what number >you begin with, this series will run into 1 or 2. If it runs into 1, it will >repeat 1-3 forever. If it runs into 2, it will repeat 2-4-6 forever.
>Write a function called joyner. joyner should have one parameter, an >integer. It should return the number of iterations required required to >reach either 1 or 2 for the first time.

Comment: @Gr3g0ry - change  `while num != 1:` to `while num > 2:` then - should work and you can eleminate the testing code.